# jQuery - Applying css style to input element

Tags: jquery, css, input, element

I am trying to check all links and change the background color of broken links field.
Here is my function

```
function CheckLinks(){
$('#new_post_links_table tbody>tr').find("input").each(function() {
    UrlExists($(this).val(), function(status){
    if(status === 404){
       $(this).css('background-color','#FC0');
    }
}); });}
```

Input fields looks like this :

```
<table id="new_post_links_table">
...
<td><input type="text" name="mp3_link[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mp4_link[]"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For some reason the css is not applying.

Note: my CheckLinks function does work, except the `$(this).css...` part. (FireBug'ed)

Note: The rows are added dynamically

EDIT : Here is the function:

```
function UrlExists(url, cb){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:      url,
        dataType: 'text',
        type:     'GET',
        complete:  function(xhr){
            if(typeof cb === 'function')
               cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, the first parameter of your `UrlExists()` function has `$(this).val`, when it should have `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Then it's a reference issue. Your inner-most `this` is not mapped to the element that is currently being tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple things wrong. You didn't include the `()` on the call to `$(this).val`, and your `this` reference within the callback doesn't refer to the element intended.

```
function CheckLinks(){
  $('#new_post_links_table tbody > tr')
    .find("input")
    .each(function(index, element) {
      UrlExists($(this).val(), function(status){
        if(status === 404) $(element).css('background-color','#FC0');
      }); 
    });
}
```

Keep in mind when doing this you might run into some snags with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

You might want to modify your `UrlExists` function to run through a proxy script on your server. You could do something like the following:

```
$.getJSON('checklink.php', { location: url }, function ( data ) {
  callback.apply( null, data.status );
});
```

On your backend, test the URL and send out the response via JSON:

```
$response = array( 
  'location' => $location, 
  'status' => $status 
);
echo json_encode( $response );
```

This way your JavaScript communicates with your back-end, and has no problem with origin control.

Comment: Ok fields back color did change. but the url was not broken. Edit: Ok I am going to check if that is enabled in my server.

Comment: @xperator You cannot just hit random URLs with JavaScript. Which urls are you trying to test?

Comment: They are on same server. They look like this `http://www.dl.mysite.com/momeni/momeni-09.mp3` I use nginx + ISPConfig. `www.dl.mysite` is treated as a different site in ISPConfig and the script I am trying is in `mysite.com/at-admin`

Comment: So effectively they are on two different domains. The browser cannot know that they are "physically" on the same device

Comment: I marked as accepted answer for the time being. Because Css problem is solved. Now the url issue is related to back-end. I need some time to dig this. Thanks a lot you are giving too much info on this :-)

Comment: @JonathanSampson I checked the server. Nginx was already compiled with http headers module. And I added proper directives. So there should be no problem at server side. The code still not working And about JSON and proxy thing: Sorry but I have no idea what JSON is and how to setup that proxy. I would really be grateful if you could point to some direction to get know JSON and the proxy thing. Thanks!

Comment: @xperator JSON is "JavaScript Object Notation." It lets you illustrate objects, replete with properties, etc., in a way that can be passed about as a string. `"[{ foo:bar }]"` is a simple example. PHP can convert arrays to JSON strings with the `json_encode()` function. Once that text is sent back into jQuery, you can access properties like this: `Object.property;`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thanks for the info. I Also read some online document to get more familiar with it. And I just got your idea. You mean instead of checking a file existance from client side, We send the url to a php page and return the result to our js function.I tried to understand how the query string is sent and how the php reacts But I couldn't. I am not good with array variables. I don't want a code or anything, Don't get me wrong. Just show me how it works and I will make a lot of use from it. Would you please explain the php part? Is the JSON query sent like a get request ?

Comment: @xperator We've gone beyond the scope of this question. If you ask another, I'll be happy to assist further.

Comment: @JonathanSampson ok I asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426857/php-json-check-broken-links

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that this is no longer referring to the input. You should add a variable to store the input so you can access it within closure

```
var input = $(this);
UrlExists($(this).val(), function(status){
  if(status === 404){
     input.css('background-color','#FC0');
  }
});
```

Comment: Um... I entered a valid link and a broken one. The valid url starts downloading and the broken doesn't change background color.

Comment: Then you should finally expose the UrlExists() function to us :-)

Comment: You might want to post something so we can check it out then! :)

Comment: @devnull69 Exposed ^_^ sorry for being late

Comment: Still looks like a reference issue to me.

Comment: @PeteLada wait a minute, maybe I am testing the urls the wrong way. I believe that the urlexist function I use is for the file on same server, right ? Tell me a url example plz. Edit: I don't think url is the issue. Tested with alert() and it worked.

Comment: @xperator It is for files on the same server ONLY ... due to the SOP. It will only work for external URLs if the external server is configured to have Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to your server

Answer (score 0):

Does that function know that there are added rows dynamically? While ago I've had similar issue. Problem was that jQuery didn't know that there are added new rows with some content. Try console out what is under $(this) in function and tell us what result have You get.