# PHP-JSON : Check broken links

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, curl

First time trying to use JSON.
 Here is my checklink.php :

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // $retcode > 400 -> not found, $retcode = 200, found.
    if ($retcode == 400){
    return "false";
    }else{
    return "true";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
$response = array( 
  'location' => $location, 
  'status' => $status 
);
$rr = url_exists($response['location']);
echo json_encode( $rr );
```

JS part :

```
function UrlExistsNew(url, callback) {
  $.getJSON('checklink.php', { location: url }, function ( data ) {
  callback.apply( null, data.status );
});
}
...
UrlExistsNew($(this).val(), function(status){
        if(status === "false") $(element).css('background-color','#FC0');
      }); 
...
```

It seems the php page is not returning result to json query.

**Edit : Note that I forgot to install curl and enable it in my server. I Hope no one miss this.**

Comment: you are not returning any result at all except true or false? where is the json?

Comment: @thecodeparadox I don't understand what you trying to ask. I have no idea what to do on both php and json side. What you mean where is the json ?

Comment: Try some debbugging tools like firebug or chrome developers tool..

Comment: @Vytautas I am using firebug to mark breakpoints and see if js is getting callback result from php or not.

Comment: so post your response.. becouse both answers should fix your issue unles there is something else.. go to console tab and show what you can see there.

Comment: @Vytautas I marked the `callback.apply...` line but it doesn't break at this part. My guess is that the problem is from php side.

Comment: Thats why I asked to check response from server..

Comment: @Vytautas Sorry mate, I didn't know about console tab. I am just a beginner. I just checked the console tab now and it shows 500 Internal error server for every url.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10828/discussion-between-xperator-and-vytautas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, After doing test and trials for 8 hours. I finally got this working. Thanks a lot to [**Vytautas**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486349/vytautas). He teached me a lot. Mostly how to debug.

For anyone who wants to check broken links using JSON + PHP + CURL :

1. First of all, Check if you have **curl** installed and enabled in your server.
2. Those who don't understand curl : If there is a response from your url, there will be a status code (like 200 or 404). If the url entered is blank, invalid or anything like that, It will return status code 0
3. If you can't get the proper response from php page, use FireBug (Console Tab) to check the headers and responses. Also use breakpoint to see if variables are passing correctly.

Here is the php code :

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) // These 2 line here are for debugging.
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));

    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retcode;
}
$response = array(
  'status' => url_exists($_GET['location'])
);
echo json_encode($response)
```

I was doing 2 thing wrong in php. I should have used `$_GET['location']` instead of `$location` And the other was `$response` instead of using a second variable.

And the js function :

```
function UrlExistsNew(url, callback) {
  $.getJSON('checklink.php', { location: url }, function ( data ) {
  callback.call( null, data.status );
});
}
```

Another thing I was doing wrong in js was passing callback to the function. I should have used `callback.call` instead of `callback.apply`

Simple usage :

```
UrlExistsNew($(this).val(), function(status){
        if(status === 404) $(element).css('background-color','#FC0');
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `$rr = url_exists($response['location']);` to

`$rr = array("status"=>url_exists($response['location']));`

to get the json response as you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
$rr = url_exists($response['location']);
echo json_encode( array('status' => $rr) );
```

And try this:

```
UrlExistsNew($(this).val(), function(status){
   if(!status) $(element).css('background-color','#FC0');
});
```

Comment: Tried your update. Still not working. I think something is missing. When I put breakpoint at `$.getJSON('checklink.php', { location: url }, function ( data ) {` It does stop but it doesn't at `callback.apply( null, data.status );` line